# Cannot change my Apple ID when attempting to sign in to download from the App Store

Tags: macos, mac-appstore

When attempting to download an app from the App Store, I am unable to change the Apple ID as the box is disabled, as shown below. How can I change the Apple ID?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Store Menu > Sign Out. Then you should be able to sign in to another ID.

Comment: Does not work if the original Apple ID has installed software on the Mac (such as iMovie) and you're trying to update the software. Better answer here: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/129773/app-store-asks-me-for-a-password-but-wont-let-me-change-the-apple-id