# how can i change the apple id on App Store?

Tags: macbook-pro, itunes, applications

On my 2009 MacBook, my friend signed into his Apple ID to check it. Now, I can't sign back into mine to download things.

Does anyone know how to get my Apple ID to sign me back in?

Answer (score 1):

In the Mac App Store, go to the Store menu -> Sign Out. This will allow you to sign out of the store.

Note, if he made any purchases during that time, downloaded any apps and/or accepted the updates for the iWork/iLife applications, they may b tied to their AppleID and won't process under yours.

Comment: Better answer here: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/129773/app-store-asks-me-for-a-password-but-wont-let-me-change-the-apple-id